# Can I ask help for a software such as Catia?

Tags: support

I have a problem for a CAO software I'm using and I want to know if I can ask for help for that software on this site ?

Comment: Well, no. Software support should go into Super User. But be aware that there might no audience who is familiar with the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends:

- Questions about CATIA programming (e.g. automation scripts, using the CAA API) belong on Stack Overflow.
- Questions about using CATIA belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).
- Questions about installing and setting up CATIA on Unix could be asked on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or Super User. Personally, I'd pick Unix & Linux.
- Questions about designing with CATIA *may* be suitable for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions). I'm not 100% certain if the site accepts CAD/CAO questions, you'll have to do a bit of research on your own.

Comment: Okay. Understood. Thanks.